# Why aren't my objects being pushed to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am making a program and I want to push javascript objects to local storage, i don't want to use any other method than local storage. I get one item however i am not getting an additional items added to the local storage array. here is my javascript code:

***UPDATED FOR NEW CODE***

```
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.setAttribute("method", "POST");

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || '[]')

if (data == null) {
  data = new Array();
}

var add = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
add.addEventListener('onclick',validate);
console.log(add);

function validate() {
  var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
  var relation = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0].value;

  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];

  var myObj = {"age": age, "relation": relation};

  data.push(myObj);

  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))

  alert(data);
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage can only save strings. Use `localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))` to save and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || '[]')` to read

Comment: when using var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data') || '[]')

I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:4

as an error

Comment: Add a try/catch around  the JSON parse line.

Comment: fixed the error, had to delete my old json object, but now whenever i load the page i still get a blank array, no matter how many elements i add